# Error in matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, error-propagation

Let's say that I have a matrix where each entry has it's own standard error. $\textbf{A} \pm \textbf{$\delta$ A}$. What would be the error of $Tr(\textbf{A}^2)$?

Is the error of $\textbf{A}^2$ just $\delta \textbf{A}^2 = \textbf{A}\textbf{$\delta$ A}+\textbf{$\delta$ A} \textbf{A}+ \delta \textbf{A} \delta\textbf{A}$ ?

Comment: You don't know that $\textbf{A} $ and $ \textbf{$\delta$ A}$ commute

Comment: @RossMillikan SORRY, I was already thinking on the trace's error. I edited the question.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  You can show it from $(\textbf{A} + \textbf{$\delta$ A})^2-\textbf{A}^2$

Comment: @RossMillikan but the error propagation is more subtle, right? $\delta (A^2)_{ij} = \sum_k |A_{ik}| \delta A_{kj} + \delta A_{ik} |A_{kj}| $  in absolute values

Comment: The previous was exact, but does not express the error in the components.  It also does not make use of the fact that $\textbf{$\delta$ A}$ is small, so its square can be neglected.  In your last you have neglected the squared term, which is fine.  It doesn't make sense to take the absolute values of the components without also taking the absolute values of the deltas, which will give you an upper bound to the change in a component.

Comment: Well, $\delta \textbf{A}$ is a matrix of standard errors, so they are always positive.

Comment: We weren't given that.  It was just an unknown error in $\bf A$